# Not able to update session values Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, controller

I am trying to save some and update my data in Spring session but its not working. I am sending data to controller with ajax, data is recieved by controller. I tried for few hours but not able to figure out the problem. here is my controller code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pages/CreateQuestion")
@SessionAttributes({"question", "preview", "qparameters", "qhparameters"})
public class CreateQuestionController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/SaveQuestion/two", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseObject saveQuestionTwo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res, ModelMap map) {
        ResponseObject obj = null;
        try {

            int auth = UserAuthentication.checkAuthentication();
            if (auth > 0) {
                String question = request.getParameter("question");
                String preview = request.getParameter("preview");
                String[] params = request.getParameterValues("params[]");
                String[] hparams = request.getParameterValues("hparams[]");
                if (question != null && question.length() > 5) {

                    QuestionStepOne one = (QuestionStepOne) map.get("one");

                    if (one.getParamiterised().equals("Yes")) {
                        if (params == null && hparams == null) {
                            obj = new ResponseObject("e", "Please provide data.");
                        } else {

                            if (params != null && hparams != null) {
                                setSessionValue(request, "qparameters", params);
                                setSessionValue(request, "qhparameters", hparams);
                                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n add both");
                            } else if (params == null && hparams != null) {
                                setSessionValue(request, "qhparameters", hparams);
                                removeSessionValue(request, "qparameters");
                                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n add Hparam and remove param");
                            } else if (params != null && hparams == null) {
                                setSessionValue(request, "qparameters", hparams);
                                removeSessionValue(request, "qhparameters");
                                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n add param and remove hparam");
                            }
                            setSessionValue(request, "question", question);
                            setSessionValue(request, "preview", preview);
                            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
                            if (params != null && params.length > 0) {
                                list.add(params);
                            }
                            if (hparams != null && hparams.length > 0) {
                                list.add(hparams);
                            }
                            obj = new ResponseObject("s", "Y", list);
                        }
                    } else {
                        setSessionValue(request, "question", question);
                        setSessionValue(request, "preview", preview);
                        removeSessionValue(request,"qparameters");
                        removeSessionValue(request,"qhparameters");
                        obj = new ResponseObject("s", "N");
                    }

                } else {
                    obj = new ResponseObject("e", "Please enter question to be saved");
                }
            } else {
                obj = new ResponseObject("e", "You must be logged in");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            System.out.println(getSessionValue(request,"question"));
            System.out.println(getSessionValue(request,"preview"));
            System.out.println(getSessionValue(request,"qparameters"));
            System.out.println(getSessionValue(request,"qhparameters"));
            return obj;
        }
    }

    private static Object getSessionValue(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        return request.getSession().getAttribute(key);
    }

    private static void setSessionValue(HttpServletRequest request, String key, Object obj) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(key, obj);
    }

    private static void removeSessionValue(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute(key);
    }
}
```

I tried with ModelMap also:

```
 map.put("qparameters",params);
```

this also not working.

**EDIT :** I am using Ajax for request:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'SaveQuestion/two',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                question: contentForTest,
                preview: content,
                params: params,
                hparams: hparams
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Before sending response i am printing the values which are write but in jsp its not reflected.

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript cannot access session variables. Respond with the required updates the body of the response.

Comment: If your session state is not being updated on certain attributes. Check the request and logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the following will work : `request.getParameterValues("params[]")`, because I don't think you have a param in you page named `params[]`. Instead, you can add `@RequestParam (required = false) String[] params` in your method signature (and do it for all your params).

Then, as you declared `@SessionAttributes`, putting those attributes in your model will add them into session. But you may need to use `org.springframework.ui.Model` instead of `ModelMap`, because the latter is deprecated. Then do a `model.addAttribute("params", params)`.

Comment: request.getParameterValues("params[]") is working for me. There is no method to remove attribute from Model. I need to remove some attributes if needed. how can i do that?

Comment: `model.asMap().remove()`. Also when you're done with your model, you have to call `sessionStatus.setComplete()` to empty your session attributes

Comment: setComplete() is for clearing all the session attributes but i dont want to remove all. i want to remove selected attributes.

Comment: As I said : `model.asMap().remove()` to remove a particular attribute, and `sessionStatus.setComplete()` to remove them all when you're done (instead of calling remove for each attribute you may or may not have pt in your model

Comment: `if (map.containsAttribute("qparameters")) { map.asMap().remove("qparameters"); System.out.print("removed"); }`  i tried this for removing which did'nt worked. removed is printed in console.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript cannot access session variables. Respond with the required updates the body of the response